# Using Racket, create a function that returns a Boolean if all numbers are odd? or even?

Tags: racket

I am stuck on this question. In fact, the code keeps running and doesn't end. Any suggestions?

(check-expect (all-elements? even? (list 1 2 3)) false)

(check-expect (all-elements? even? (list 2 4 6)) true)

(check-expect (all-elements? odd? (list 1 3 5)) true)

(define (all-elements? predicate lst)

(cond

[(empty? lst) false]

[(predicate (first lst)) true]

[else (all-elements? predicate lst)]
)
  )

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (all-elements? predicate lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) true)
        ((predicate (first lst)) (all-elements? predicate (cdr lst)))
        (else false)))
```

*Different approach*:

```
;; make `and` as a function
(define (my-and a b) (and a b))

(define (all-elements? predicate args) 
  (foldr my-and #t (map predicate args)))
```

```
(all-elements? odd? '(1 3 5))
;; #t
```

or as a variadic function:

```
(define (all-elements? predicate . args) 
  (foldr my-and (map predicate args)))
```

then one can type:

```
(all-elements? odd? 1 3 5 7 9) ;; #t
```

Comment: Thank you Gwang-Jin. I was definitely overthinking that.

Comment: @SuzRenae Welcome!